# problems with excel's application.evaluate command in vba

Tags: string, excel, vba, replace, evaluate

I have a problem with some excel code that I am having trouble getting my head around.

Okay so I am using the application.evaluate command in excel vba, office 2007.

If i have `Evaluate("SIN(45)")` it returns a nice predicted number. However if I do `Evaluate("eq")` the code crashes.

eq is an equation i am reading in from excel. the equation is: `3*x^2+5*x+1`. It is passed in as a string. to make sure this happened I placed it in another variable that I had defined as a string. I replace the x's in the equation using excel's replace function. `equation = Replace(equation, "x", temp)`.

However, when i get to the evaluate the code breaks down and I am not sure why. `Total = Total + Evaluate("equation")`. Any help is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the problem lies where you references a string "equation" instead of the equation string.

I would do

`Evaluate(equation)` or
`Evaluate(Replace(equation, "x", temp))` instead, note without the quotations *"* around equation and that would yield a valid answer.

Hope this help.

Comment: Charles Williams has a nice description of some of the many quirks of using Application.Evaluate here: http://www.decisionmodels.com/calcsecretsh.htm